# Change canvas the color of cell onTouch down

Tags: java, android, canvas, drawing

I am actually doing a game on Android Studio based on grid which I draw with this:

```
public void dessin(Canvas canvas){
    paint.reset();
    TenGame theGame=gam.getTenGame();
    canvas.drawColor(Color.YELLOW);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    for(int x=0;x<canvasWidth;x+=cellSize){
        canvas.drawLine(x,0,x,canvasWidth,paint);
    }
    for(int y=0;y<canvasWidth;y+=cellSize){
        canvas.drawLine(0,y,canvasWidth,y,paint);
    }

    paint.setTextSize(50);
    paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    PositionList plist=theGame.getSelectedGroup();

    for(int x=0;x<5;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<5;y++){
            Position p=new Position(x,y);
            if (theGame.get(p)!=null) {
                canvas.drawText(Integer.toString(theGame.get(p)), (x * cellSize) + 15, (cellSize + y * cellSize) - 15, paint);
            }
            else{
                canvas.drawText("", (x * cellSize) + 15, (cellSize + y * cellSize) - 15, paint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I get this:
gridgame:
[image: gridgame]

And I would like, when I touch a cell in the grid, to change the background's color.
I think the best solution here for me is to do a drawRect(), but I don't know which dimension should I do.
I have the game model in the library, which I can get the Position (x, y).

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably be better off by using a GridPane as this will make the process of drawing raster lines and adding an event handler to each cell way easier.